# Getting Error for MockMvc perform() Methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test, mockmvc

I am creating a Spring MVC Controller test. Compiler is showing errors for methods shown below in bold. Am I missing some library or something in my code? Any suggestions?

I am using following dependencies:

> ```
>   <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
>         <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>junit</groupId>
>         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
>         <version>4.11</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
>         <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
>         <version>1.3</version>
>         <scope>test</scope>
>     </dependency>
> ```

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PostAuthorize;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvcBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;

import com.zerosolutions.view.form.LoginCredentials;

@RunWith(value=SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:dispatcher-servlet.xml")
public class TestingFrontController {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getLoginSignupPage() throws Exception{
        this.mockMvc.perform(**get**("/"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(forwardedUrl("login"))
        .andExpect(model().attribute("loginCred", **any**(LoginCredentials.class)));
    }

}
```

Comment: what are you importing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add following to import these methods

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
```

Comment: That helpled, but still getting for `get()` and `any()`

Comment: How this works?